# Using php to get all translatable text from a website/html-page

Tags: php, html, translation, strip-tags, language-translation

I'm trying to set up a translation tool to translate websites. What I want to do is import `html-code` and get all translatable texts from that site.

One idea would be to use `strip_tags`, but it would ignore strings that could be translated such as alt-texts, title-texts and probably others that I don't have on my mind yet. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Look at DOMDocument in the PHP manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to parse HTML and extract text yourself. As you, probably, already know,  parsing HTML with regular expressions is [A Bad Idea (tm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). SO, the only right solution is to parse DOM of the document. On this step you are free to use any tools including standard [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class.

If you are looking for some libraries or scripts to help, i would suggest to look on [html2text](http://code.google.com/p/iaml/source/browse/trunk/org.openiaml.model.runtime/src/include/html2text/html2text.php) which could be used commercially. As i see, it doesn't support attributes for `<img>` tags, but it's very easy to fix (use `<a>` tag as example).

If you are looking for some automated text extraction, then you should definitely look on something like [Bolierpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/).

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use the [DOM Crowler component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) from Symfony2, which is a nice wrapper around php DOM functions and start from there.